# Unity InterceptionBehavior with InjectionConstructor

Tags: unity-container, unity-interception

Is it possible to configure a custom InterceptionBehavior with InjectionConstructor?  In other words, how do you tell Unity which constructor on your InterceptionBehavior to use.

In order to trace the method flow in our application, I currently have four InterceptionBehavior classes that deal with tracing.  The only difference between them is the TraceSwitch that they use in order to configure tracing, so we can turn on/off tracing in the different layers.  I would like to only have one custom TraceInterceptionBehavior, which I could use ConstructorInjection in order to set the TraceSwitches.

Something like this (example only, does not compile).  This would be where I register the business services into the container.  There would be similar registrations for the other layers such as controllers and repositories etc.

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    serviceTypes,
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    getLifetimeManager: WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
    getInjectionMembers: c => new InjectionMember[]
    {
        new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
        new InterceptionBehavior<TraceInterceptionBehavior>(
        // this is how I would do it if interception behavior supported constructor injection
                    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ITracer>(), 
                                             TraceSwitches.ServiceBegin, 
                                             TraceSwitches.ServiceEnd))

            });
    }
```

The constructor of the custom TraceInterceptionBehavior that I am trying to call:

```
public TraceInterceptionBehavior(ITracer tracer, TraceSwitch traceSwitchBegin, TraceSwitch traceSwitchEnd) : this(tracer)
{
    TraceSwitchBegin = traceSwitchBegin;
    TraceSwitchEnd = traceSwitchEnd;
}
```

As I understand, this is possible if using the PolicyInjection and CallHandler from the older Unity such as the following example but I am at a loss on how to do it with the new version of Unity.

```
container.Configure<Interception>()
.AddPolicy("SomePolicyName")
.AddCallHandler<SomeCustomInterceptor>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<SomeType>(), new ResolvedParameter<SomeType2>());
```

**Update**

As pointed out by @DanielJ.G below, the interception behavior class can be registered into the container just like any other class.  For each layer that I want trace interception using a different trace switch, I just set up a named registration for the interception behavior.  The below code would be for the service layer.  There are similar registrations for controllers and repositories using a different name and traceswitch configuration.

```
container.RegisterType<TraceInterceptionBehavior>("ServiceTraceInterceptionBehavior",
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ITracer>(),
    TraceSwitches.ServiceBegin,
    TraceSwitches.ServiceEnd));

container.RegisterTypes(
    serviceTypes,
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    getLifetimeManager: WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
    getInjectionMembers: c =>
    new InjectionMember[]
        {
            new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
            new InterceptionBehavior<TraceInterceptionBehavior> "ServiceTraceInterceptionBehavior")
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure `TraceInterceptionBehavior` as if it were any of the registered types in Unity, so you could add the following to your container registration:

```
container.RegisterType<TraceInterceptionBehavior>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ITracer>(), 
                             TraceSwitches.ServiceBegin, 
                             TraceSwitches.ServiceEnd));
```

You have a full sample in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qi6buP).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  As I want to configure my custom trace interceptor differently for each layer, I ended up registering my `TraceInterceptionBehavior` for each layer using a named registration.